# How to make a gallery of images automatically fit in close together in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

Okay, so I have a webpage that has a 'gallery' of images that are all of different sizes (all the same width, though), and they're all fit into image containers with borders, and padding for a little title underneath them. I want them all to fit together snugly so that there's no awkward large space between pictures of different sizes, because right now as you can see in the picture, the webpage seems to want to keep all the images in horizontal rows and not fill up the empty space that's left.

For example, I want two of the images that are not tall to fit into a row next to one that is tall so that all space is being used up.

This is what it looks like: [screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTe1l.jpg)

This is what the CSS for the gallery looks like: `

```
.galleryHolder{
                   text-align: center;
               margin-left: 55px;
                top: 20px;
        }   


div.gallery {
    margin: 30px;
    border: 2px solid darkgrey;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    border-radius: 2%;
    opacity: .4;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.title {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    Font-family: Century Gothic;
    Color: crimson;
}`
```

and here is what a sample of the HTML for each image looks like:

```
  <div class = "galleryHolder"> 


 <div class="gallery">
    <img src="images/ForPurchase/purchase11.jpg" alt="Snowy Owl Landing" width="320" height="400">

  <div class="title">"Snowy Angel"</div>
</div> 

</div>
```

Is there a possible way to make all these images fit into all possible gaps to make everything look snugly put together? Answer would be greatly appreciated, this is for a project that is due in a few hours.

Comment: Go look up masonry.js

Comment: This is a really stupid question but I'm a beginner. How would I apply that to my page? Is it just adding a script?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation: http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started

Comment: I tried it by what the instructions say and it makes a total mess of the page. Any other options?

Comment: What you're looking for essentially has always been done with masonry.js. Very soon, we will be able to do this with pure CSS using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which is finally stable enough to use on production sites, and [CSS Grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) which unfortunately aren't ready quite yet. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibeF6rbzD70) is a good presentation on how we will approach issues like yours.